# How to use wildcards to delete all text between two characters in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards, text-processing

I've been able to figure out some simpler wildcard searches before but this one is kicking my butt and I'd love some help.

Here's some of the text in my MS Word document:

> decidere v1 (v11)
>
> decido, is, ere, cidi (63) : to fall/drop/hang/flow down; to sink/drop; to fail, fall in ruin; to end up, to die; —decidere perfect indicative active 3rd plural
>
> usque r
>
> usque, prep. + acc (598) : up to (name of town or locality); —usque

In every line that contains commas, I want to cut everything from the first comma (inclusive) to the paragraph return (exclusive). In other words, when I'm done I want the text to look like this:

> decidere v1 (v11)
>
> decido
>
> usque r
>
> usque

Is there a way that I can do this using wildcards?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah, okay—thanks so much! Will do.

Comment: @DavidPostill Should I edit this question or ask a new one?

Comment: Edit the question and provide text samples of before and after.

Comment: Also, please add normal tags next time (tool you're using, related topic), not just one functionality that kind of fits.

Comment: @Destroy666 Can you reopen the question? Then we can give him a proper answer on it

Comment: @JoelDerfner so that you can continue your work: in the "Find what" field type ,*^13 and in the replace with field type ^p. Detailed instructions will follow as soon as your question can is open for answering again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Place cursor at the beginning of the document
2. Press `CTRL + H` to open the “Find and Replace” function
3. In the bottom left click on “More” and then activate the “Use wildcards” option
4. In the “Find what” field type `,*^13`
5. In the “Replace with” field type `^p`
6. Click on “Replace All”
   [image]

Explanation:
The `*` will combine everything between the first comma and the line break (`^13`). Usually you should also be able to use `^13` in the replace field to insert the line break again, but I found that this sometimes create a weird error. If you use `^p` instead, it will work properly.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It baffles me that there isn't like an online course on how to use wildcards. I've seen several guides but they've tended to be fairly opaque.